# How to change fill colour of empty cells in ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have a data set that has some missing values for the x variable. For example, the dataframe below shows 181930 and 610 has a full set of x variables, 1-7, while 1044,1114, etc only have one.

```
label   xvar value
181930  1    0
181930  2    0
181930  3    1
181930  4    0
181930  5    0
181930  6    0
181930  7    1
610  1    0
610  2    0
610  3    0
610  4    0
610  5    1
610  6    1
610  7    0
1044  1    0
1114  1    0
1156  1    1
1378  1    0
1834  1    1
```

I would like to produce a heatmap using ggplot showing cells that have values of 1. This is my code so far, however for the labels with only one xvar shows a blank cell and rather I would like for it to have a colour (white) to match the 0 values.

```
ggplot(activeDF,aes(xvar,factor(label)))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value),colour='white')+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=round(seq(0,7)))+
  scale_fill_gradient(high=brewer.pal(10,'PiYG')[8],low='white',na.value = 'white')
```

Unfortunately, the na.value didn't work for me. Here is a photo:
[image: plot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the straightforward approach to doing something in *ggplot2* is to manipulate your dataset prior to plotting.  In this case, expanding your dataset so it contains all combinations you want to plot is an option.

I use `tidyr::complete` for this along with grouping from package *dplyr*.  This adds a row for `xvar` of 1 through 7 for every `label`.  If the row doesn't currently exist, it fills in missing values with `NA`.  `NA` seems sufficient for your use case, but you could also use the `fill` argument to set the missing values to 0 or something.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

longdf = activeDF %>%
     group_by(label) %>%
     complete(xvar = 1:7)

longdf

# A tibble: 49 x 3
# Groups:   label [7]
   label  xvar value
   <int> <int> <int>
 1   610     1     0
 2   610     2     0
 3   610     3     0
 4   610     4     0
 5   610     5     1
 6   610     6     1
 7   610     7     0
 8  1044     1     0
 9  1044     2    NA
10  1044     3    NA
# ... with 39 more rows
```

Using the expanded dataset, your plot now expands through the entire range of the data and so the tiling is complete.

```
ggplot(longdf, aes(xvar, factor(label)) ) +
     geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = 'black') + 
     scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(0, 7))) +
     scale_fill_gradient(high = brewer.pal(10, 'PiYG')[8], low='white', na.value = 'white')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that worked wonderfully. Thank you for the suggestion! Instead of the `scale_fill_gradient` I ended up switching to `scale_fill_manual` since my values are 0 or 1. However `ggplot2` adds a legend entry for NA values. Would you happen to also know how to prevent `ggplot2` from adding this separate legend entry? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh You should be able to set your `breaks` to remove `NA` from the legend.

Answer (score 0):

try this `+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))`

```
ggplot(activeDF,aes(xvar,factor(label)))+
geom_tile(aes(fill=value),colour='white')+ 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=round(seq(0,7)))+
scale_fill_gradient(high=brewer.pal(10,'PiYG')[8],low='white',na.value = 'white') +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. it worked, however, if I want to change the outline colour to black in order to see each cell clearly, how can I achieve this? I changed `colour='black'` for `geom_tile` however I encounter a similar issue where the blank empty cells do not have an outline